# Difference between 8GB,4Gx1 + 4G onboard, DDR4, 2666MHz and 8 GB, LPDDR3, 2133 MHz, Integrated?

Tags: laptop, memory, dell-inspiron, ramdisk

I have come across two Dell Laptops having the below RAM configuration.

1. 8 GB,4Gx1 + 4G onboard, DDR4, 2666MHz and
2. 8 GB, LPDDR3, 2133 MHz, Integrated

My concern is that 8 GB,4Gx1 + 4G onboard, DDR4, isn't this an 8GB RAM.? or just a 4GB RAM? I read many articles on internet but couldn't understand the difference between these two and which one should be preferred?

Secondly, all the configurations are same in these laptop and only difference is the RAM only. I understand DDR4 is better than LPDDR3?

**Laptop 1:** New Dell Inspiron 14 5490

**Laptop 2:** New Dell Inspiron 13 5391

Reference: https://www.dell.com/en-in/shop/laptops-2-in-1-pcs/sr/laptops/inspiron-laptops/10th-gen-intel-core-i5?appliedRefinements=19329

Comment: Onboard means that the RAM is soldered on the board. So you have one slot filled with 4GB RAM and another 4GB soldered on board (8GB in total). In case you want to upgrade the RAM memory in the future you will have only one slot. DDR4 is better for speed, LPDDR (Low Power) is better for power consumption.

Comment: I may not upgrade my RAM. Then, is it fine to go with option 1?

Comment: The difference was explained by User552853 - the choice is entirely yours and is opinion-based.